# Virtualbox NAT configuration for HTTP port forwarding

Tags: ubuntu, nat, port-forwarding, virtualbox

Hi I'm successfully installed Ubuntu server on virtualbox in macOS. Now, I want to access the ubuntu localhost either `0.0.0.0:8000` or `127.0.0.1:8080` in my host operating system.

I configured `NAT` port forwarding. The `SSH` connection in my macOS terminal works perfect. But I can't access `http` from my browser by calling `127.0.0.1:8080`.

I'm using python http.server for testing the connection

`puthon3 -m http.server`

Serving HTTP on 0.

> 0.0.0.0 port 8000 (http://0.0.0.0:8000/)

Please help me to resolve this issue. Thanks!

**Screenshots:**

[SERVER OS WELCOME SCREEN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L68vE.jpg)

[NETWORK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dyuKJ.jpg)

[PORT FORWARDING](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUStR.jpg)

Comment: @Ramhound, I referred lot of websites and tutorials shows like that only to port forwarding for http localhost to the host OS. I really don't know what you are saying and I knew something wrong, that's why I asked here question for solution ;)

Comment: @Ramhound, You are wrong brother.`NAT` virtual adapter is about attach to the real network of the Host OS as virtualbox tooltip shown. I've resolved and I am accessing on host OS's `localhost.`

Comment: Not a brother….avoid calling other users brother….

Answer (score 0):

The problem is on guest OS port. If I run `sudo python3 -m http.server 80`then `127.0.0.1:8080` is works on host machine.

So, the virtualbox portforwarding settings, there is no strict requirement to enter IP address indeed **port.**

My current working settings:

**Name   Protocol  Host IP  Host Port  Guest IP  Guest Port**

```
http       TCP                8080                  80
```